# Преобразовать список объектов в список списков пар объектов

Tags: list, kotlin

На входе есть список объектов

```
["яблоко","груша","абрикос","помидор","арбуз"]
```

На выходе надо получить такое

```
[["яблоко","груша"],["абрикос","помидор"],["арбуз"]]
```

Т.е. последовательные пары упаковать в отдельные списки.

Сделал так

```
fun <T> List<T>.toPairs(): List<List<T>> =
    mapIndexed { index, t -> Pair(index, t) }
            .groupBy { it.first / 2 }
            .map { it.value.map { it.second } }
```

Но как-то не нравится куча преобразований:

```
List<T> 
-> List<Pair<Int, T>> 
-> Map<Int, List<Pair<Int, T>>> 
-> Map<Int, List<T>> 
-> List<List<T>>
```

Может можно как-то проще?

PS Интересует именно цепь преобразований, а не цикл с кучей временных переменных - так я и сам умею

Comment: в 1.2 есть [chunked](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html). Внутри там похоже [цикл с кучей временных переменных](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/40aa2280a58d8b7083a81fe4d357874f78a4b3f3/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/SlidingWindow.kt#L35)

Comment: @zRrr так-то у них вся библиотека работы с коллекциями из циклов с кучей переменных состоит :) Но за то мы ее и любим, что оно из кода в библиотеку убрано :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле всё очень просто. Нам надо получить пары элементов и отсеять лишние. Примерно так:

```
input
  .asSequence()
  .zipWithNext()
  .filterIndexed{index,_ -> index % 2==0}
  .toList()
```

где `input` - это лист на входе.

---

Альтернативный способ сделать то же самое —

```
input
  .asSequence()
  .windowed(size=2, partialWindows=true, step=2)
  .toList()
```

Обратите внимание на `partialWindows` — этот параметр определяет, нужно ли сохранять листы, в которых недостаточно элементов — например 1, а не два.

**UPD**

Наиболее простое решение задачи (спасибо zRrr)

```
list.chunked(2)
```

Все приведенное выше работает начиная с Kotlin 1.2

Comment: @rjhdby обновил ответ. Лишнее таки нужно потому что  там ещё сформируется лист из `["груша", "абрикос"]`

Comment: @rjhdby там можно step выставить какой надо. В данном случае 2. Сейчас опять обновлю ответ :)

Comment: ага, уже посмотрел. Спасибо!

Comment: @rjhdby Ну и windowed скорее всего круче по перфомансу чем zipWithNext, так что я бы брал его.

Comment: К слову о важности отслеживания новых фич языка...